# VScode Remote SSH: Terminal exited with output 1 when connecting to known host

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote-ssh

Until yesterday I was able to connect without any problems to the remote host using the remote ssh extension.

Today, before there was any prompt to enter my password, I got an error popup Visual Studio Code: Could not establish connection to "lxplus.cern.ch".

Also, there was this vscode notification

```
The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe /c (type "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-linux-multi-line-command-lxplus.cern.ch-916464892.sh" | ssh -T -D 53187 "lxplus.cern.ch" bash) & exit /b 0" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

Also, here is the SSH output:

```
[14:56:29.907] Log Level: 2
[14:56:29.912] remote-ssh@0.94.0
[14:56:29.913] win32 x64
[14:56:29.987] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+lxplus.cern.ch", attempt 1
[14:56:29.987] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[14:56:29.988] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[14:56:29.988] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {"lxplus.cern.ch":"linux","raspberrypi.local":"linux"}
[14:56:29.988] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[14:56:29.988] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[14:56:29.989] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[14:56:29.989] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[14:56:29.989] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[14:56:29.989] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[14:56:29.989] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[14:56:29.990] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[14:56:29.990] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[14:56:29.990] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[14:56:29.991] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[14:56:29.991] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[14:56:29.991] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[14:56:29.996] SSH Resolver called for host: lxplus.cern.ch
[14:56:29.996] Setting up SSH remote "lxplus.cern.ch"
[14:56:30.002] Using commit id "1ad8d514439d5077d2b0b7ee64d2ce82a9308e5a" and quality "stable" for server
[14:56:30.007] Install and start server if needed
[14:56:30.010] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[14:56:30.056] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreS
[14:56:30.057] > SL 3.0.2

[14:56:30.061] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 53187 "lxplus.cern.ch" bash
[14:56:30.064] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[14:56:30.516] > & was unexpected at this time.
> ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[14:56:30.516] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[14:56:31.716] "install" terminal command done
[14:56:31.717] Install terminal quit with output: ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[14:56:31.717] Received install output: ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[14:56:31.718] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[14:56:31.719] Resolver error: Error: 
    at g.Create (c:\Users\George\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.94.0\out\extension.js:1:583926)
    at t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\George\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.94.0\out\extension.js:1:582540)
    at t.tryInstall (c:\Users\George\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.94.0\out\extension.js:1:680469)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async c:\Users\George\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.94.0\out\extension.js:1:642848
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\George\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.94.0\out\extension.js:1:646166)
    at async t.resolve (c:\Users\George\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.94.0\out\extension.js:1:643898)
    at async c:\Users\George\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.94.0\out\extension.js:1:723024
[14:56:31.725] ------
```

I can connect without an issue from the terminal using ssh, and I can connect from another device using the Remote SSH extension wituout any problems.

The issue seems to be the terminal(?)

VScode suggested I check out https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/troubleshoot-terminal-launch, but I could not find something to help me.

I tried deleting the .vscode-server folder on the remote machine, but it did not fix the issue.

I believe the problem comes before trying to even contact the server.

Comment: Did you try to trobleshooting it:
- Download vscode server from [this site](https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:latest/server-linux-x64/stable) on remote side.
- Unzip the downloaded vscode-server-linux-x64.tar.gz to ~/.vscode-server/bin/lastest

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am not sure how to download what you are telling me. The site goes to an empty page saying "Not Found". I tried using ```wget https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:latest/server-linux-x64/stable``` but I got error 404 not found. Also, I believe the problem comes from the client (local) side since I do not even get to enter my password. Seems like the terminal refuses to run the vscode script to connect to host.